# How do you remove a 0 decimal value for some cases while keeping setprecision(2)?

Tags: c++, formatting

I am having an issue on Zybooks where it is asking me to remove the second decimal value if it is a 0 but not to remove it if it isn't. How would I fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is a little long, but it will work.
Here is the code, contains three examples...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double a = 12.01;
    double b = 23.000;
    double c = 15.40;

    //Example 1
    if ( a - floor(a) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(0);
        cout << fixed << a << endl;
    }
    else if ( (a*10) - floor((a*10)) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(1);
        cout << fixed << a << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout.precision(2);
        cout << fixed << a << endl;
    }

    //Example 2
    if ( b - floor(b) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(0);
        cout << fixed << b << endl;
    }
    else if ( (b*10) - floor((b*10)) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(1);
        cout << fixed << b << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout.precision(2);
        cout << fixed << b << endl;
    }

    //Example 3
    if ( c - floor(c) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(0);
        cout << fixed << c << endl;
    }
    else if ( (c*10) - floor((c*10)) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(1);
        cout << fixed << c << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout.precision(2);
        cout << fixed << c << endl;
    }


}
```

And here is the output...

```
12.01
23
15.4
```

To make this all a bit nicer and more convenient for your code make a method that takes in a double and prints the correct value. This will reduce number of if else statements in your code. Like this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//You can use this function to replace duplicate code
void printDouble( double numToPrint)
{

    if ( numToPrint - floor(numToPrint) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(0);
        cout << fixed << numToPrint;
    }
    else if ( (numToPrint*10) - floor((numToPrint*10)) == 0 )
    {
        cout.precision(1);
        cout << fixed << numToPrint;
    }
    else
    {
        cout.precision(2);
        cout << fixed << numToPrint;
    }

}

int main()
{

    double a = 12.40000;
    double b = 56.053;
    double c = 43.67;
    double d = 34.70;
    double e = 98.00;

    cout << "doubles are: ";
    printDouble(a);
    cout << ", ";
    printDouble(b);
    cout << ", ";
    printDouble(c);
    cout << ", ";
    printDouble(d);
    cout << ", ";
    printDouble(e);
    cout << endl;

}
```

Output is...

```
doubles are: 12.4, 56.05, 43.67, 34.7, 98
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to setprecision(1) for those cases.

I tried it and it works:

```
int main()
{
  double a = 1.1;
  double b = 1.2;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << a << endl;
  cout << setprecision(1) << b << endl;
}
```

This is the output:

```
1.10
1.2
```

Comment: Since this can have many different test cases, that suggestion is not possible since the zero could happen anytime